# Django View with ForeignKey model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I've got following in the
models.py:

```
class ArticleCategory(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField("Category", max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True, unique=True)

    def get_data(self):
        return {
            "id": self.pk,
            "category_name": self.category_name,
            "slug": self.slug,
        }

class Article(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(ArticleCategory)
    ...

    def get_data(self):
        return {
            "id": self.pk,
            ...
        }
```

views.py:

```
def articles(request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = {
        'categories': ArticleCategory.objects.all(),
        'articles': Article.objects.filter(category__id=2)
    }
    return render(request, 'wellness.html', context)
```

And everything works fine. However, I want category__id to be dynamic, so I'm changing function to be `def articles(request, id, *args, **kwargs)` and  to `'articles': Article.objects.filter(category__id=id)`
Seems like it was working with previous projects for me, but now it throws  that error every time I try to set up such behavior (tried id, slug, category_name):

```
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    articles() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
Exception Location:     .../env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py in _wrapped_view, line 23
```

Maybe something with urls.py?

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
...

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^wellness$', login_required(articles), name='wellness'),
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes indeed it's in your urls.py.

You defined a view that expects two parameters but didn't configure the `url` function to capture part of the url and pass it on as an additional parameter next to `request`.

You want to do something like this to capture a slug or id respectively:

## Slug

```
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^wellness/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/?$', login_required(articles), name='wellness'),
    url(r'^reports/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', credit_views.report),# kwargs = {"id": 9}
]
```

## Alternatively with id:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^wellness/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', login_required(articles), name='wellness'),
]
```

In the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#captured-parameters) you can find more information.